# Selecting cron expression for @Scheduled based on another configuration list property in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el, spring-expression-language

The following custom configuration properties exist in my Spring Boot (2.5.4) application:

**application.yml**

```yaml
app:
  tasks:
    - name: A
      url: http://server-a
      cron-expression: "*/5 * * * * *"
    - name: B
      url: http://server-b
      cron-expression: "*/10 * * * * *"
```

**Configuration class**

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private List<TaskEntry> tasks;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class TaskEntry {
        private String name;
        private String url;
        private String cronExpression;
    }
}
```

Now, there is also a method which shall run with the `@Scheduled` annotation. While specifying a variable expression for the `cron` argument is easy, I'm looking for a more dynamic apporach.

This `cron-expression` to be used in the `@Scheduled` annotation shall be selected by the `TaskEntry` with `name == A`. So I came up with something like this:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${app.tasks.?[name == 'A'].cron-expression}")
public void run() {
    log.info("Starting task A...");
}
```

This fails with the following message:

`Could not resolve placeholder 'app.tasks.?[name == 'A'].cron-expression' in value "${app.tasks.?[name == 'A'].cron-expression}"`

Comment: Probably easiest to turn the list into a map with `A`, `B`, ... as keys and `url` and `cronExpression` in a custom class as values. Then you can use `app.tasks.A.cron-expression`.

Comment: Agreed; also `${...}` is for simple property placeholders; to use SpEL, you need to use `#{...}` (and quote any properties within the SpEL - e.g. `cron = "#{'${app.tasks.A.partial-cron-expression}' + ' *'}"`).

Comment: Thanks @Henning, guess I'll follow this approach.